# HPA on AZURE AKS but pod are immediately going in terminating state because it showing not able to find out default volume to mount

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, hpa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWhv5.png)I'm trying to implement HPA in my project, such that whenever CPU utilization is above 15% it should auto scale pods, but HPA is working, it is creating pods but pods are going from container creating state to terminate state within a second, as pods are terminating so not able to see any pod related logs also, but  `kubectl get events` is showing:

```
"**Error: cannot find volume "default-token-chcXX" to mount into container, Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[default-token-chcXX[\][1], unattached volumes=[default-token-chcXX]: timed out waiting for the condition** "
```

[error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d4ey.jpg)

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: XXX
  namespace: XXX
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: XXX
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: XXX 
      annotations:
        timestamp: "{{ .Values.metadata.annotations.timestamp }}"  
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gui
        image: ""1.0"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: default-token-chcXX
          readOnly: true
imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 300m
            cpu: 512Mi
         requests:
            memory: 300m
            cpu: 512Mi
     nodeSelector:
        agentpool: XXX  
      tolerations:
      - key: pool-name
        operator: Equal
        value: XXX
        effect: NoSchedule   
      volumes:
      - name: default-token-chcXX
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: default-token-chcXX
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with HPA, share your deployment\pod spec

Comment: there is no issue with HPA however there is an issue with your deployment and your container or POD is not starting due to a mounting issues.

Comment: @shubhika garg Provide details about deployment or PODs log.

Comment: @HarshManvar , there no pod logs as pods are terminating within a second  , so not able to see logs

Comment: @shubhika garg Hope your deployment is not failing. are you using the PVC with your deployment and trying to scale it?

Comment: @HarshManvar pod without HPA is running fine  , and there is  no pv and pvc in our component

Comment: Attaching or mounting secret to pods volume cannot find volume "default-token-chcXX" to mount into container ?

Comment: earlier we are not mounting secret because it is AKS default secret  , so it get mounted by itself  in pod , now we have mounted  it so pod creating using HPA can use that secret@HarshManvar

Comment: Is the secret and deployment in the same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

i think your pod is crashing due to the as your secrets and config maps will be mounted as read-only volumes.

Kubernetes add its own secret at /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ it is unable to place them as /run/secrets is read-only.

Due to that maybe your pod crashes.

maybe readOnly: false won't work.

Before everything else first check your secret and volume exist as error is showing : `cannot find volume "default-token-chcXX" to mount into container`

what may be you can try out is to use **subpath**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  test: <YOUR DATA>
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: "/run/secrets/test"
          subPath: test
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          secretName: test-secret
          items:
          - key: test
            path: "test"
```

Issue : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60814

Comment: yes Im able to see secret by  command :- kubectl get secret

Comment: try changing the mount path and using the subpath

Comment: I have tried subpath , still same issue persist

Comment: that's weird so your single replica of pod running if HPA is not there ?

Comment: yes , single replica is running  , issue is with HPA pod only

Comment: really weird scenario directly terminating replicas?

Comment: yaa pods come in container creating state and then directly goes in terminating state within a second

Comment: can you try with running multiple replicas manually ?

Comment: Kubectl scale deployment <deployment name> --replicas=5

Comment: I tried with mutiple replica manually , and with that also it running  fine , issue only comes with pod creating through HPA

Comment: that's weird never faced an issue like the same.

Comment: @shubhikagarg have you fixed the issue ? I'm facing the same issue, can you please share the solution if it's fixed ?